# Console shows zero tests skipped

Tags: testng

I am trying to learn the concept of skipping test methods in TestNG. This is possible via enabled=false or in the testng.xml specify the method name under exclude tag. However when I execute the xml file the console report shows 0 skips. The test method is actually skipped but the console report shows 0 skips.
Am I missing something there? Why is the console showing 0 skips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of skipped tests in TestNG is not very transparent. From the docs:

> If a method depended upon fails and you have a hard dependency on it
>   (alwaysRun=false, which is the default), the methods that depend on it
>   are not marked as FAIL but as SKIP.  Skipped methods will be reported
>   as such in the final report (in a color that is neither red nor green
>   in HTML), which is important since skipped methods are not necessarily
>   failures.

So disabled tests are not considered as *skipped*. Skipped tests are enabled tests which don't make sense to run because a dependency of them has failed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!. Is there a way to get a report on test methods which were "skipped" via enabled=false and via exclude tag in xml file

Comment: Hi @Amit Not that I know :(. I'm not even sure if it's possible to extend testng to report on this.